# Cricket bat crack effect

Tags: cricket, equipment

I brought a cricket bat last month. I had a couple of sessions in nets and it started cracking along the grain at the shoulder of the bat. Is it normal or do I need to repair it?

[image: bat[1]

Comment: Did you knock it in first?

Comment: yes I did Knock it.

Answer (score 1):

Any cracks on a bat, no matter where, are not acceptable. The bat will wear out fast, and it won't produce the needed stroke.
Also, it will start producing a sort of recoil on the grip when hitting the ball, especially at a pace.
You can try if repairing works here.